# How to implement autocomplete in MVC app?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

Can anoyone lead me to code to implement autocomplete for a textbox
where the data comes from a database table server side?

This is in ASP.NET MVC application. Using SQL Server.

Malcolm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [article](http://flux88.com/blog/jquery-auto-complete-text-box-with-asp-net-mvc/) should provide the basic framework for the first half and then instead of using the CSV you would query the database.